# rollup plugins not recognizing installed rollup

Tags: rollupjs

I installed rollup globally:

```
npm install -g rollup
```

Then, I tried to install a plugin, locally:

```
C:\wwwroot\speech-to-text [master +9 ~0 -0 !]> npm install rollup-plugin-json
npm WARN rollup-plugin-babel@4.0.3 requires a peer of rollup@>=0.60.0 <1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rollup-plugin-commonjs@9.1.8 requires a peer of rollup@>=0.56.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN speech-to-text@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ rollup-plugin-json@3.1.0
updated 1 package in 1.895s
```

It gives warnings that rollup isn't installed. Does anyone know why? Here is me checking the version, in case you doubt that rollup was actually installed:

```
C:\wwwroot\speech-to-text [master +9 ~0 -0 !]> rollup -v
rollup v0.66.2
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe the problem is that you have installed rollup in the global context.

You may try to install rollup this way

```sh
npm install rollup --save-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

These plugins (`rollup-plugin-commonjs` & `rollup-plugin-babel`) have `rollup` listed as their peer dependency:

- https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/blob/master/package.json#L24
- https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/blob/master/package.json#L38

Currently peer dependencies are not searched among global packages. I'm not sure what are the reasons behind it. See also:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9857